# python module ZipFile get base folder using regex

Tags: python, python-re

Assume this zip file "acme_example.zip" contains below content of the files/folders :

```
acme/one.txt
acme/one1.txt
acme/one2.txt
acme/one3.txt
acme/one4.txt
__MACOSX
.DS_Store
```

And i am using this below script

```
    output_var = []
    skip_st = '__MACOSX'
    with ZipFile('acme_example.zip','r') as ZipObj:
        listfFiles = ZipObj.namelist()
        for elm in listfFiles:
            p = Path(elm).parts[0]
            if p not in output_var:
                output_var.append(p)
        return re.sub(skip_st, '', ''.join(str(item) for item in output_var))
```

This above script will exclude "__MAXOSX" but is there a way to also exclude ".DS_Store"  so that we will only return "acme" as folder name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you iterate over the values, that would be better to exclude them at this moment, also as they are already strings, you can simplify the code in the join part

```
skip_st = ['__MACOSX', '.DS_Store']
with ZipFile('acme_example.zip','r') as ZipObj:
    listfFiles = ZipObj.namelist()
    for elm in listfFiles:
        p = Path(elm).parts[0]
        if p not in output_var and p not in skip_st:
            output_var.append(p)
    return ''.join(output_var)
```

---

So you know, here's how you can filter at the end

- with a list

  ```
  skip_st = ['__MACOSX', '.DS_Store']
  # ...
  return ''.join(item for item in output_var not in skip_st)
  ```
- with a pattern

  ```
  skip_st = '__MACOSX|.DS_Store'
  # ...
  return re.sub(skip_st, '', ''.join(output_var))
  ```